# JQuery, Function orchestration

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, orchestration

I am stuck on jQuery 1.4.3 on a current project and need some advice on how best to orchestrate the following..

Let's say I have two functions whom both perform ajax calls, and I only want to call the second one if the first one succeeds. With that said, there are also times in my application where I will call *function a* without needing to call *function b*. Therefore it wouldn't make sense to put the call to the second function within the first functions success method.

I'd like to do something like,

```
function doStuff(){
    functionA().success( functionb() ).failure();
}
```

I typically orchestrate by using .done(); but that was introduced in jQuery 1.5, and again I am stuck on 1.4.3 for now.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it makes sense to call it in the `functionA()` success handler. Just call it conditionally.

```
// Set a variable to determine if you will need to call functionB()
var youNeedToCallFunctionB = true;
// And call functionA()
functionA();

// Function definition:
function functionA() {
  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function() {
      if (youNeedToCallFunctionB) {
        // Call functionB() in the success handler when needed...
        functionB();
      }
    }
  });
}

functionB() {
  // Some other AJAX call...
}
```

Even better, pass a parameter to `functionA()` which determines whether or not to call `functionB()`

```
functionA(youNeedToCallFunctionB) {
  // same thing as above, but pass the parameter
}

// Called as
functionA(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I was looking for more of a "service" type pattern but this is interesting and perhaps the best way to do it in JS.